# Accept donations through Credit Cards in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a business Paypal account, and want to implement a Donation Button on my website. Problem is when i click on donation button, it force me to Pay only through Paypal, i mean no option to pay through Credit cards also. Whats the problem?

Comment: Your question is way too broad, there could be a dozen of possible answers, although you can pay with credit card through(/with) paypal

Comment: please explain your comment, i didn,t understand. How to activate Credit Card option in my Business account ? I guess you can solve my problem, please tell me what do you want to know ......i will explain

Comment: AFAIK. theres an option that must be checked on your account to accepts payments from credit cards

Comment: yes, i have found the same statement on other places, but what is that option exactly !!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]There is usually a QA box like this when you integrate their button [image: PayPal Donate button redirected page]

There is a headline "**Don't have a PayPal account?**" thats where they can choose to donate by Credit Card

**EDIT:** For clarification, this is when someone has pressed the button on your page.

Comment: Thanks for your kind information and precious time, just tell me one thing...when i click on "CONTINUE", it take me to create a new Paypal account, is it due to country location??? i am from Pakistan....Please also share the next screen after clicking on "CONTINUE", so that i will see.

Comment: please reply me , am waiting...........if you provide me ur email id, i will send the next screen, so that you can better understand my problem...please